# matlab shuffle elements of vector with the same sequent of the same number

Tags: matlab, vector, shuffle

I have the following vector
`a = 3 3 5 5 20 20 20 4 4 4 2 2 2 10 10 10 6 6 1 1 1`
does anyone know how to shuffle this vector with the same elementsnever be seperate?
something like bellow
`a = 10 10 10 5 5 4 4 4 20 20 20 1 1 1 3 3 2 2 2 6 6`
thank you, best regard...

Comment: Are the groups always guaranteed to be unique such that you wouldn't have: `3 3 5 5 3 3 4 4`?

Comment: yes i have this matrix firts
a = [3 2;5 2;20 3;4  3;2  3;10  3;6  2;1  3]
i did something, and my matrix become:
a = [3 2;3 2;5 2;5 2;20 3;20 3;20 3;4  3;4  3;4  3;2  3;2  3;2  3;10  3;10  3;10  3;6  2;6  2;1  3;1  3;1  3]
and now I need to random the value of the first row...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unique` combined with `accumarray` to create a cell array where each group of values is placed into a separate cell element. You can then shuffle these elements and recombine them into an array.

```
% Put each group into a separate cell of a cell array
[~, ~, ind] = unique(a);
C = accumarray(ind(:), a(:), [], @(x){x});

% Shuffle it
shuffled = C(randperm(numel(C)));

% Now make it back into a vector
out = cat(1, shuffled{:}).';

%   20 20 20  1  1  1  3  3 10 10 10  5  5  4  4  4  6  6  2  2  2
```

Another option is to get the values using `unique` and then compute the number that each occurs. You can then shuffle the values and use [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) to expand out the result

```
u = unique(a);
counts = histc(a, u);

% Shuffle the values
inds = randperm(numel(u));

% Now expand out the array
out = repelem(u(inds), counts(inds));
```

Answer (score 3):

A very similar answer to @Suever, using a loop and logical matrix rather than cells

```
a = [3 3 5 5 20 20 20 4 4 4 2 2 2 10 10 10 6 6 1 1 1];

vals = unique(a); %find unique values
vals = vals(randperm(length(vals))); %shuffle vals matrix

aout = []; %initialize output matrix
for ii = 1:length(vals)
     aout = [aout a(a==(vals(ii)))]; %add correct number of each value
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach:

```
a = [3 3 5 5 20 20 20 4 4 4 2 2 2 10 10 10 6 6 1 1 1];
[~, ~, lab] = unique(a);
r = randperm(max(lab));
[~, ind] = sort(r(lab));
result = a(ind);
```

Example result:

```
result =
     2  2  2  3  3  5  5 20 20 20  4  4  4 10 10 10  1  1  1  6  6
```

It works as follows:

1. Assign unique labels to each element of `a` depending on their values (this is vector `lab`);
2. Apply a random bijection from the values of `lab` to themselves (the random bijection is represented by `r`; the result of applying it is `r(lab)`);
3. Sort `r(lab)` and get the indices of the sorting (this is `ind`);
4. Apply those indices to `a`.